# Chrome extensions - unload event page immediately

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome extension developing. I've written an extension that shows a notification every time a new tab is created. It works, however if I open a tab and immediately open another tab, the notification will be shown only for the first tab.

On the [Chrome extension documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html#lifetime) I read this:

> Once the event page has been idle a short time (a few seconds), the chrome.runtime.onSuspend event is dispatched.

Apparently it explains why there was no notification for the second tab. Is it possible to unload the event page immediately (i.e. once the notification is shown), without waiting a few seconds?

This is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "notification test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "notifications" ],
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"], "persistent": false }
}
```

**background.js**

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    '48.png',
    'hello',
    'this is a test'
);

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
    notification.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code a)**

***manifest.json***

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "notification test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "notifications" ],
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"], "persistent": false },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    "48.png"
  ]
}
```

***background.js***

```
function notify(tab){
    console.log(tab);
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
        '48.png',
        'hello',
        'this is a test'
    );
    notification.show();
}

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(notify);
```

In this solution you will see two notifications if new tab is created first time/immediately after another tab because of https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162543. But here you are struck to event pages instead of background pages.

**Code b)**

By Making event page to background page you can get desired functionality running; However this do not use event page if you are particular about it.

***manifest.json***

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "notification test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "notifications" ],
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"], "persistent": true },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    "48.png"
  ]
}
```

***background.js***

```
function notify(tab){
    console.log(tab);
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
        '48.png',
        'hello',
        'this is a test'
    );
    notification.show();
}

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(notify);
```